# Custom timerange in QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I'm currently doing queries like

```
where startTs > '2021-04-18T00:00:00.000000Z'
      and startTs <= '2021-05-17T00:00:00.000000Z'
```

It's not 1 month of data but intervals around 25 days. I wondering if there is a shorter syntax to query data between timestamps in QuestDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shorter syntax would be

```
where startTs > '2021-04-18'
      and startTs <= '2021-05-17'
```

so that 0 time is optional. Time can be specified up to any precision

```
where startTs > '2021-04-18T12'
      and startTs <= '2021-05-17T12'
```

also there is special syntax to query interval of 29 days but it includes start microsecond of `2021-04-18T00:00:00.000000Z` and excludes end microsecond of `2021-05-17T00:00:00.000000Z`

```
where startTs IN '2021-04-18;29d'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding here that QuestDB has supported the BETWEEN syntax now for a while https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/where/#between